# How to fetch data from multi tables in nosql using SEMBAST plugin

Tags: flutter

I am not able to fetch data when multi table which are having relationship . so can any one help as per the below image

[image]

finally i need data like
`ORDER_ID`, `USER_FULL_NAME`, `PRODUCT_NAME`, `PRODUCT_PRICE` from 3 different table .

please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sembast, does not provide a way to query multiple stores in one join query. However getting an entity by id (here a user or a product) is almost immediate (`store.record(id).get(db)` or `store.records(ids).get(db)`) so I think your best bet is to query the order_items store and fetch the users and products by ids.

Basically using 3 requests in a transaction to ensure data integrity should perform the join you want.